# MS Word 2011 Custom dictionary item format in plist file on Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, ms-office

I have a project to programmatically install custom dictionary into Microsoft Word 2011 for mac. I have made the version for MS Word 2008, but now microsoft has changed the format.
Can anybody help me to find out the format of the custom dictionary entry in the com.microsoft.office.plist for MS WORD 2011 for mac. I do make some research and I found most of the fields inside the entry, but some fields are not clear.

Comment: What fields are not clear? What do they look like? Not everyone has MS Office and of those not many would like to go fishing for the file. Easiest for you to post the things that are giving you trouble.

Comment: Hello, 

thanks for reply.
The point is that the entry is in the binary format and reverse engineering is needed to find out the structure of it. As I wrote before sample entry you can see in the file ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.office.plist on your Mac if you have Office 2011

Comment: Right. And posting an example copy (or a link to it on a file-hosting service) will help those who don't have it try to help you regardless.

Comment: I'm very interested in knowing your solution for Office 08 as I have a solution for Office 11 but not for 08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closed. All the fields are found. Cannot disclose it here, sorry.